Why am I getting an error message when searching for certain facts in 10-Q forms?
I'm fairly new to Python and would really appreciate any help I can get. I apologise if I call something by the wrong name. I am trying to build a tool using Edgar APIs that grabs info from financial documents such as 10-Ks and 10-Qs, and then can be used to make graphs out of it. Here is my code:
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import urllib.parse

def get_cik(ticker=None, company_name=None, headers=None):
    if not ticker and not company_name:
        raise ValueError("You must provide either a ticker symbol or a company name.")
    
    company_tickers_response = requests.get(
        "https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json",
        headers=headers
    )

    company_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(company_tickers_response.json(), orient='index')

    company_data['cik_str'] = company_data['cik_str'].astype(str).str.zfill(10)

    if ticker:
        company_row = company_data[company_data['ticker'] == ticker.upper()]
    else:
        company_row = company_data[company_data['title'].str.lower() == company_name.lower()]
    
    if company_row.empty:
        raise ValueError(f"Company '{ticker or company_name}' not found.")
    
    cik = company_row.iloc[0]['cik_str']
    return cik

def retrieve_financial_data(cik, concepts, form_type="10-K", start_year=None, end_year=None, headers=None):
    combined_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for concept_name in concepts:
        try:
            encoded_concept_name = urllib.parse.quote_plus(concept_name)
            url = f'https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyconcept/CIK{cik}/us-gaap/{encoded_concept_name}.json'
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            response.raise_for_status()

            # Print the raw JSON response for debugging
            print(f"\nJSON response for {concept_name}:\n", response.json())

            possible_units = ['USD', 'USD/shares', 'Shares', 'Percentage', 'Per share', 'USD/unit', 'Items']
            data = None
            for unit in possible_units:
                data = response.json().get('units', {}).get(unit, None)
                if data:
                    print(f"Data found for unit: {unit}")
                    break

            if not data:
                print(f"No data found for concept '{concept_name}' in form type '{form_type}'.")
                continue

            df = pd.DataFrame(data)

            # Check if 'end' column is present
            if 'end' not in df.columns:
                print(f"No 'end' date found for {concept_name}. Data cannot be processed.")
                continue

            # Convert 'end' and 'start' columns to datetime
            df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], errors='coerce')
            df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.get('start', None), errors='coerce')

            # Drop rows with missing 'end' dates
            df = df.dropna(subset=['end'])

            if df.empty:
                print(f"No valid data found after processing 'end' dates for {concept_name}.")
                continue

            if start_year:
                start_year = int(start_year)
            if end_year:
                end_year = int(end_year)
            
            available_years = df['end'].dt.year.sort_values().unique()
            
            if start_year and end_year:
                nearest_start = min(available_years, key=lambda x: abs(x - start_year))
                nearest_end = min(available_years, key=lambda x: abs(x - end_year))
                df = df[(df['end'].dt.year >= nearest_start) & (df['end'].dt.year <= nearest_end)]
                print(f"Data retrieved for the nearest available years between {nearest_start} and {nearest_end}.")
            else:
                print("Retrieving data for all available years.")

            df['period'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['end'] - row['start']).days if pd.notnull(row['start']) else -1, axis=1)

            if form_type == "10-K":
                filtered_df = df[(df['form'].isin(['10-K', '10-K/A'])) & (df['period'].between(360, 370) | df['period'].eq(-1))].copy()
                filtered_df.sort_values(by=['end', 'form'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
                filtered_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)
                filtered_df.sort_values('end', inplace=True)
                print(f"10-K/10-KA values for {concept_name}:")
                display(HTML(filtered_df[['end', 'val', 'form']].to_html()))

                combined_df = filtered_df.copy()

            elif form_type == "10-Q":
                is_cumulative = df['period'].eq(-1).all()

                if is_cumulative:
                    filtered_df_10q = df[(df['form'] == '10-Q') & (df['period'].between(88, 92) | df['period'].eq(-1))].copy()
                    filtered_df_10k = df[(df['form'].isin(['10-K', '10-K/A'])) & (df['period'].between(360, 370) | df['period'].eq(-1))].copy()
                    
                    filtered_df_10q.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)
                    filtered_df_10k.sort_values(by=['end', 'form'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
                    filtered_df_10k.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)

                    combined_df = pd.concat([filtered_df_10q[['end', 'val']], filtered_df_10k[['end', 'val']]])
                    combined_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)
                    combined_df.sort_values('end', inplace=True)

                    print(f"Cumulative values for {concept_name} (including 10-Qs and final 10-K/A):")
                    display(HTML(combined_df[['end', 'val']].to_html()))
                else:
                    filtered_df_10q = df[(df['form'] == '10-Q') & (df['period'].between(88, 92))].copy()
                    filtered_df_10k = df[(df['form'].isin(['10-K', '10-K/A'])) & (df['period'].between(360, 370))].copy()

                    filtered_df_10q.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)
                    filtered_df_10k.sort_values(by=['end', 'form'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
                    filtered_df_10k.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)

                    q4_data = []
                    all_quarters_data = []

                    for _, row in filtered_df_10k.iterrows():
                        q1_end_date = row['end'] - pd.DateOffset(months=9)
                        q2_end_date = row['end'] - pd.DateOffset(months=6)
                        q3_end_date = row['end'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)

                        q1_val = filtered_df_10q.loc[filtered_df_10q['end'].between(q1_end_date - pd.Timedelta(days=5), q1_end_date + pd.Timedelta(days=5)), 'val'].values
                        q2_val = filtered_df_10q.loc[filtered_df_10q['end'].between(q2_end_date - pd.Timedelta(days=5), q2_end_date + pd.Timedelta(days=5)), 'val'].values
                        q3_val = filtered_df_10q.loc[filtered_df_10q['end'].between(q3_end_date - pd.Timedelta(days=5), q3_end_date + pd.Timedelta(days=5)), 'val'].values

                        if q1_val.size > 0 and q2_val.size > 0 and q3_val.size > 0:
                            q4_value = row['val'] - (q1_val[0] + q2_val[0] + q3_val[0])
                            q4_data.append({'end': row['end'], 'val': q4_value})
                            all_quarters_data.extend([
                                {'end': q1_end_date, 'val': q1_val[0], 'quarter': 'Q1'},
                                {'end': q2_end_date, 'val': q2_val[0], 'quarter': 'Q2'},
                                {'end': q3_end_date, 'val': q3_val[0], 'quarter': 'Q3'},
                                {'end': row['end'], 'val': q4_value, 'quarter': 'Q4'}
                            ])
                            print(f"Q4 Calculation for {row['end'].year}: {row['val']} ({row['form']}) - ({q1_val[0]} + {q2_val[0]} + {q3_val[0]}) = {q4_value}")

                    if q4_data:
                        all_quarters_df = pd.DataFrame(all_quarters_data)
                        all_quarters_df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(all_quarters_df['end'], errors='coerce')
                        all_quarters_df = all_quarters_df.dropna(subset=['end'])
                        all_quarters_df.sort_values('end', inplace=True)

                        combined_df = all_quarters_df[['end', 'val', 'quarter']].copy()
                        combined_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)
                        combined_df.sort_values('end', inplace=True)

                        print(f"Quartile values for {concept_name} (including calculated Q4):")
                        display(HTML(all_quarters_df[['end', 'val', 'quarter']].to_html()))

            combined_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['end'], keep='first', inplace=True)
            combined_df.sort_values('end', inplace=True)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error retrieving data for {concept_name}: {e}")

    return combined_df

def scale_y_axis(df):
    if df['val'].empty:
        return df, 'Value'
    
    max_value = df['val'].max()
    
    if max_value >= 1_000_000_000:
        scale = 1_000_000_000
        unit = 'USD (Billions)'
    elif max_value >= 1_000_000:
        scale = 1_000_000
        unit = 'USD (Millions)'
    elif max_value >= 1_000:
        scale = 1_000
        unit = 'USD (Thousands)'
    else:
        scale = 1
        unit = 'USD'
    
    df['scaled_val'] = df['val'] / scale
    return df, unit

def dynamic_plot(data_dict, concept_name, title=None, y_label=None, x_axis_choice='end'):
    for company, data in data_dict.items():
        if not data.empty:
            plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

            # Ensure data is sorted by end date
            data.sort_values(by='end', inplace=True)

            # Adjust quarter positioning
            def adjust_quarter_pos(date, quarter):
                if quarter == 'Q1':
                    return date.replace(month=3, day=31)
                elif quarter == 'Q2':
                    return date.replace(month=6, day=30)
                elif quarter == 'Q3':
                    return date.replace(month=9, day=30)
                elif quarter == 'Q4':
                    return date.replace(month=12, day=31)
                return date

            if 'quarter' in data.columns:
                data['adjusted_end'] = data.apply(lambda row: adjust_quarter_pos(row['end'], row['quarter']), axis=1)
            else:
                data['adjusted_end'] = data['end']

            x_axis_data = data['adjusted_end']

            data, y_axis_unit = scale_y_axis(data)
            plt.plot(x_axis_data, data['scaled_val'], marker='o', linestyle='-', label=company)

            if title:
                plt.title(title.format(company=company))
            else:
                plt.title(f'{company} - {concept_name} Over Time')

            # Set x-axis major ticks to be only the years, hiding the quarter labels
            plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
            plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
            plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator([1, 4, 7, 10]))  # Minor ticks for quarters

            plt.xlabel('Year')
            plt.ylabel(y_label if y_label else f'{concept_name} ({y_axis_unit})')
            
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.legend()
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.show()

def main():
    tickers = input("Enter the ticker symbols of the companies (comma-separated, e.g., TSLA, AAPL): ").strip().split(',')
    concepts = input("Enter the financial concepts you want to retrieve (comma-separated, e.g., OperatingExpenses, CostsAndExpenses): ").strip().split(',')
    form_type = input("Enter the form type you want to retrieve (e.g., 10-Q, 10-K): ").strip()
    start_year = input("Enter the start year (leave blank for all available data): ").strip()
    end_year = input("Enter the end year (leave blank for all available data): ").strip()

    custom_title = input("Enter a custom title for the graph (leave blank for default): ").strip()
    custom_y_label = input("Enter a custom label for the Y-axis (leave blank for default): ").strip()
    x_axis_choice = input("Enter the column name to be used for the X-axis (leave blank for default 'end'): ").strip()

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'your-email@example.com'}

    data_dict = {}

    for ticker in tickers:
        ticker = ticker.strip().upper()
        try:
            cik = get_cik(ticker=ticker, headers=headers)
            print(f"CIK for {ticker}: {cik}")

            data = retrieve_financial_data(cik, concepts, form_type=form_type, start_year=start_year, end_year=end_year, headers=headers)
            if not data.empty:
                data_dict[ticker] = data

        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

    if data_dict:
        combined_concept_name = ', '.join(concepts)
        dynamic_plot(data_dict, concept_name=combined_concept_name, title=custom_title, y_label=custom_y_label, x_axis_choice=x_axis_choice)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


However, when I attempted to use it to search up NetCashProvidedByUsedInInvestingActivities for NextDecade Corp (NEXT) CIK = 1612720, I get this response: Error retrieving data for NetCashProvidedByUsedInInvestingActivities: 'end', despite the fact that there is quarterly data in the JSON response. Can anyone see any issues with my code? I'd also be very grateful for more general advice on how to improve it. Thank you so much!


However, when I attempted to use it to search up NetCashProvidedByUsedInInvestingActivities for NextDecade Corp (NEXT) CIK = 1612720, I get this response: Error retrieving data for NetCashProvidedByUsedInInvestingActivities: 'end', despite the fact that there is quarterly data in the JSON response.

Indeed there is quarterly data, but some of it is filtered out by
filtered_df_10q = df[(df['form'] == '10-Q') & (df['period'].between(88, 92))].copy()
since there are entries like
                "start": "2015-01-01",
                "end": "2015-06-30",
                "val": -117300000,
                "accn": "0001213900-15-006025",
                "fy": 2015,
                "fp": "Q2",
                "form": "10-Q",
                "filed": "2015-08-13"

where the period in days from start to end is not between 88 and 92. Then
the data is only processed if all of Q1, Q2 and Q3 have values, and from that NEXT data set there's only Q1 data filtered, which is leading to an empty DataFrame combined_df in the end.
Possibly the way you filter here is not actually what you want and it might be in order to disregard that period.
